# get files url reques in action of mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want get file url request in controller .
when come this request

```
http://localhost:4616/Images/Users/mohammadhossein21@gmail.com/hm2.jpg
```

or this request

```
http://localhost:4616/Images/Users/mohammadhossein21@gmail.com/4230.pdf
```

I can get this request in The following action of `Images Controller`

```
public ActionResult Users(string Email, string Name)
        {
            string subPath1p = Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~/")).Parent.FullName + "\\SUPPORT_USERSFILES\\" + Email+"\\"+Name+".pdf";

            return File(subPath1p, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should customize routing: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ActionResult, use FileResult as return type.